# fabric task error when prompting for password

Tags: python, fabric, paramiko

I'm having an error I can't seem to get past.  I have a simple fabric task that must be run as a different user on the remote system, e.g:

```
def update():
    env.user = 'otheruser'
    #~ env.password = 'otherpass'  # this works, but I don't want it here.
    with cd(env.sitefolder):
        run('hg pull -u')
```

If I run this with env.password hardcoded it works.  If I use `fab -p otherpass update` it works too.  If I omit it [the docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/) say I will get prompted.  This is true, but it doesn't work.  Every time after entering the password I get this error:

```
> fab dev update
[darkstar] Executing task 'update'
[darkstar] run: hg pull -u
[darkstar] Login password: 
ERROR:paramiko.transport:Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
...
Fatal error: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Aborting.
```

Using fabric 1.2.2 on Ubuntu Natty.  I also tried the env.no_keys option but it didn't change anything.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prompt for the password yourself!

```
def update():
    env.user = 'otheruser'
    env.password = getpass.getpass('Enter password: ')
    with cd(env.sitefolder):
        run('hg pull -u')
```

`getpass` is part of the standard library, it's just a `raw_input` that doesn't echo what you type

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Been so long that I'll need to dig up that code.  ;)

Comment: Thanks again, just got back to the code.  Upgrading to fabric 1.3.2 didn't help!  I added getpass and it worked on the first try.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if target is out of memory/disk space. Restarting and/or solving memory/disk space problems can solve this.